# Is it possible to support iPhoneX for some view controllers in the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, viewcontroller

I have an  application which developed before iPhone X release. My question is the following, can I add iPhoneX support for only newly created view controllers? I mean some view controllers will have iPhoneX friendly UI some not in the same app. For my new view controllers I'm using safe area but UI is broken for iPhoneX.
For the app I guess Apple will not allow partial support for iPhoneX.
Just wondering is it possible or not and how if answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either all or none. If your app uses a Launch Screen storyboard and is built with a Base SDK of iOS 11 or if your app uses launch images and includes an iPhone X launch image then your whole app is presumed to work on an iPhone X. You will need to make sure all screens work correctly.

Think about what a terrible user experience it would be to use an app on an iPhone X where some views use the whole screen and some views only use part of the screen.

Comment: Totally agree with you maddy. Just want to make sure.